How to show this function is decreasing?
The function is   $$g(y) = \frac{\int_0^\pi e^{y\cos\theta} \cos\theta \sin^{n-1}\theta d\theta}{y\int_0^\pi e^{y\cos\theta} \sin^{n-1}\theta d\theta} $$ Its defined on positive reals. I want to show that this function is decreasing, its monotonicity is important for my work. I have tried different methods like analyzing the first derivative, taking the log of the function and trying to show that that is decreasing, but I have not been able to show this result.
Edit: Here n is a positive integer.

By substitution
$$d\theta  \cos ^k(\theta ) \sin ^{n-1}(\theta ) e^{y \cos (\theta )}\text{/.}\, \left\{\cos (\theta )\to s,\sin (\theta )\to \sqrt{1-s^2},d\theta \to \frac{ds}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}\right\}=s^k \left(1-s^2\right)^{\frac{n}{2}-1} e^{s y} ds$$
on gets
$$F(y,n)=\int_{-1}^1 \left(1-s^2\right)^n e^{s y} \, ds = \sqrt{\pi } \ \Gamma (n+1) \ \, _0\tilde{F}_1\left(n+\frac{3}{2};\frac{y^2}{4}\right)$$
$$H(y,n)=\partial_y \log (F(y,n))=\frac{2 \left(\frac{2 \log \left(n! \, _0\tilde{F}_1\left(n+\frac{3}{2};\frac{y^2}{4}\right)\right)+\log (\pi )}{y}-\frac{2 \log (y) I_{n+\frac{3}{2}}(y)}{I_{n+\frac{1}{2}}(y)}\right)}{\left(2 \log \left(n! \, _0\tilde{F}_1\left(n+\frac{3}{2};\frac{y^2}{4}\right)\right)+\log (\pi )\right){}^2}$$
Too complex, to check for monotonicity
     Plot[Evaluate[H[y, { -1/2, 1/2, 3/2, 5/2}]], {y, 0, 4}]


     Plot[Evaluate[D[H[y, { -1/2, 1/2, 3/2, 5/2}], y]], {y, 0, 4} ]



Using the regularized hypergeometric function, just as Roland F answered, the result is simply, in terms of  the modified Bessel function of the first kind
$$g_n(y)=\frac 1 y\,\frac{I_{\frac{n+1}{2}}(y)}{I_{\frac{n-1}{2}}(y)}$$
Expanding as a series around $y=0$
$$g_n(y)=\frac{1}{(n+1)}-\frac{y^2}{(n+1)^2 (n+3)}+\frac{2\,
   y^4}{(n+1)^3 (n+3) (n+5)}+O\left(y^6\right)$$
So, at least, $g_n(y)$ starts decreasing.
Asymptotically,
$$g_n(y) =\frac{1}{y}-\frac{n}{2
   y^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{y^3}\right)$$

Thanks for the reply. Could you elaborate how you could represent g(y) in terms of modified Bessel functions?
